# shell if statement always returning true

Tags: shell, if-statement

I want to check if my VPN is connected to a specific country. The VPN client has a status option but sometimes it doesn't return the correct country, so I wrote a script to check if I'm for instance connected to Sweden. My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
 country=Sweden
 service=expressvpn

while true; do
   if ((curl -s https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address  | grep $country | grep -v "grep" | wc -l) > 0 )
   then
      echo "$service connected!!!"
  else
      echo "$service not connected!"
      $service connect $country
 fi;
 sleep 5;
 done
```

The problem is, it always says "service connected", even when it isn't. When I enter the curl command manually, wc -l returns 0 if it didn't find Sweden and 1 when it does. What's wrong with the if statement?
Thank you
Peter

Answer (score 3):

`(( ))` enters a math context -- anything inside it is interpreted as a mathematical expression. (You *want* your code to be interpreted as a math expression -- otherwise, `> 0` would be creating a file named `0` and storing `wc -l`'s output in that file, not comparing the output of `wc -l` to 0).

Since you aren't using `))` on the closing side, this is presumably exactly what's happening: You're storing the output of `wc -l` in a file named `0`, and then using its exit status (successful, since it didn't fail) to decide to follow the truthy branch of the `if` statement. [Just adding more parens on the closing side won't fix this, either, since `curl -s ...` isn't valid math syntax].

Now, if you *want* to go the math approach, what you *can* do is run a command substitution, which replaces the command with its output; *that* is a math expression:

```
# smallest possible change that works -- but don't do this; see other sections
if (( $(curl -s https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address | grep $country | grep -v "grep" | wc -l) > 0 )); then
```

...if your `curl | grep | grep | wc` becomes `5`, then after the command substitution this looks like:

```
if (( 5 > 0 )); then
```

...and that does what you'd expect.

---

That said, this is silly. You want to know if your target country is in curl's output? Just check for that directly with shell builtins alone:

```
if [[ $(curl -s https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address) = *"$country"* ]]; then
  echo "Found $country in output of curl" >&2
fi
```

...or, if you *really* want to use `grep`, use `grep -q` (which suppresses output), and check its exit status (which is zero, and thus truthy, if and only if it successfully found a match):

```
if curl -s https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address | grep -q -e "$country"; then
  echo "Found $country in output of curl with grep" >&2
fi
```

This is more efficient in part because `grep -q` can stop *as soon as it finds a match* -- it doesn't need to keep reading more content -- so if your file is 16KB long and the country name is in the first 1KB of output, then `grep` can stop reading from `curl` (and `curl` can stop downloading) as soon as that first match 1KB in is seen.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the `curl -s https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address  | grep $country | grep -v "grep" | wc -l` statement is text. You compare text and number, that is why your if statement does not work.

This might solve your problem;

```
if [ $(curl -s https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address  | grep $country | grep -v "grep" | wc -l) == "0" ] then ...
```

Comment: `grep ... | grep -v grep` is an (unfortunate, bad-practices) idiom for grepping through `ps` output; it's not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

That worked, thank you for your help, this is what my script looks now:

```
#!/bin/bash
country=Switzerland
service=expressvpn

while true; do
if curl -s https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address | grep -q -e "$country"; then
  echo "Found $country in output of curl with grep" >&2
  echo "$service not connected!!!"
  $service connect Russia
else
  echo "$service connected!"
fi;
sleep 5;
done
```

Comment: I'm glad this worked! Please use the checkbox next to an answer to flag it as what worked for you.